# GTM Setup for tracking "click to display" text on wordpress

Tags: html, google-tag-manager

[Code and GTM Setup Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk3gU.jpg)

I have tried a few variations in how I set my triggers, but none of the ways I have tried have actually started to track test clicks. The client has click to display text to show their phone numbers, ideally so that we can track how many visitors are coming to the site to get the phone contact details. I will include some code below. I am not sure if it is my syntax or if I am forgetting something outside of this setup. GTM is installed correctly and tracking standard google analytic information. Thanks in advance.

Previously I have tried to limit the trigger based on the class, but I have instead added and moved to ID.

Comment: Please provide code or screenshot of the trigger.

Comment: Hi Matus, Thanks for taking a look. It's all in the image link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk3gU.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky part of GTM because when you have nested elements like this:

```
<div>
 <span>
  <h2>
```

It is sometimes difficult to say what exact element is clicked.

Your triggers are set for `<div>` (based on ID you have in your screenshot) but I suspect when you click the actual element that is picked up is one of the `<span>` ones. To fix it, firstly in GTM go to variables tab -> Configure Built-in variables and make sure "Click Classes" is enabled.

Then setup a trigger like this:
[image]

This one will listen to one of those spans you have there.

Usually my approach to click events is: before I setup the trigger I enable the preview mode with GTM so that I see GTM's debugger console. Then click on an element - this action will generate click event on left hand event log. Select it and you will be able to see exact element that is being clicked with it's IDs and classes. Then it's easy to setup the trigger.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Matus Thank you so much! This is working now and I really appreciate you taking the time to have a look and post a reply.

Comment: No worries Chris, I'm glad it is working. Could you please accept the answer when you get a chance? thanks :)